# Previous declaration and conflicting types

Tags: c

Ive got a problem. I cant compile my program even though everything seems fine. It comes up with those errors":1.c:6:5: error: conflicting types for ‘sumaa’
int sumaa(int tab[],int a){
^~~~~
1.c:3:5: note: previous declaration of ‘sumaa’ was here
int sumaa(int,int);
^~~~~
I dont know why. Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int sumaa(int,int);
int suma(int*,int*);

int sumaa(int tab[],int a){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i= 0; i<a;i++)
        sum+= tab[i];
    return sum;
}

int suma(int* a,int* b){
    int  suma = 0;
    int* pt;
    for (pt = a; pt != b; pt++)
        suma+=*pt;
    return suma;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int tab[n];
    for(int i = 0; i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&tab[i]);
    }
    sumaa(tab,n);
    suma(tab,tab+n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the first parameter as an array in the prototype.

```
int sumaa(int*,int);
```

Comment: ... or better: `int sumaa(int[], int);` which is exactly the same as `int sumaa(int*, int);` but shows the intention better

Comment: @PlacekThe Mark the answer as "Accepted" if it help you.